# Bash String Format Comparison with Wildcards

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I am fairly new to bash scripting and was trying to echo only lines that match a specific formatting. I have this code so far:

```
LINE=1
while read -r CURRENT_LINE
    do 
        if [[ $CURRENT_LINE == ??-?-??? ]]
        then
            echo "$LINE: $CURRENT_LINE"
        fi    
        ((LINE++))
done < "./new-1.txt"
```

The text file contains number sequences on each line that match the following format: "12-3-456", but also contains sequences that are in different formats as well, such as "123-89203-9420" or "123-456-7890". I can't quite understand why the if statement inside the while loop does not result to True on lines that match the formatting. I've tried using the * as well, but using it gives me incorrect results.

Here are the contents of the text file new-1.txt. I want the script to output "Line 1: 11-1-111", but it doesn't output anything.

```
11-1-111
222-22-2222
333-33-3333
444-444-4444
555-555-5555
```

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand. `?` matches a single character, and a *pattern* is implicitly anchored at both the beginning and end. So `??-?-???` only matches strings that are exactly 8 characters long, with the 3rd and 5th characters required to be hyphens. (The other six can be any character.)

Comment: It will be clearer if you can provide the example of `new-1.txt` and your expected result. I assume your file contains other words than the hyphenated numbers in the same line as chepner comments.

Comment: I've added the contents of the text file to the post, for some reason it isn't echoing anything, even though the first line matches the format of the if statement in the script. Could it possibly be the newline character?

Comment: Thank you for the update. You are right about the newline character. If the file contains the `CR LF` line breaks,
the script fails. Please try `dos2unix` to remove the trailing CR characters or change
the `if` statement to something like `if [[ $CURRENT_LINE == ??-?-???$'\r' ]]`.
Using regex (as jared_mamrot answers) will also work.

Comment: @tngoy : Your pattern works for me for `11-1-111`, but of course not for the other example strings you posted. If you **never** get a true match, it means that the variable contains something else than you think it does. I suggest that you print the content of the variable with `xxd <<<$CURRENT_LINE` before testing it, and inspect the output.

Answer (score 0):

In the `regex` parlance, the `?` makes the character or selection optional, ie , a character/selection is allowed to occur at most one time but zero occurrences are also tolerated.

However, the `==` operation is not the regex matching operator. It is `=~`.

So changing your `if` clause to the below would do the job.

```
[[ $CURRENT_LINE =~ "^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{3}$" ]]
```

Here

- The `^` specifies the beginning of regex and `$` the end. So we have a tight coupling of the pattern to match
- `[0-9]` denotes a range, here any number from zero to nine.
- The `{n}` mandates that the preceding character/selection should match exactly `n` number of times

<sup>Note : You can also use a more verbose `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`</sup>